# xcode не устанавливается background для tableView

Tags: uitableview, xcode7

main.storyboard я сделал tableView, растянутый от хедера до самого низа экрана. Сделал кастомную ячейку с темным бэкграундом. В общем в эдиторе это выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после чего настроил сам tableView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прошу обратить внимание, что параметр background у меня темный. Но при вытаскивании навигационной панели (вид для которой описываю выше) я вижу следующую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть background в моем случае белый, совсем не темный. в vievDidLoad для этого контроллера я так же скрываю пустые ячейки

```
table.tableFooterView = UIView()
table.tableFooterView?.hidden = true
```

Подскжите, в каком напрвлении копать? Цель - сделать так, чтобы белая часть tableView была одного цвета с ячейками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант - перетянуть пустой View в пустое место таблицы (где написано Table View) и ему уже указать нужный цвет.

Comment: Но ведь тейбл растянут у меня по высоте до низу, почему я не могу задать для него бэкграунд? У меня высота таблицы и количество ячеек будет динамически меняться, в зависимости от того авторизован юзер или нет, то есть вариант с заглушкой не годится

Comment: Сейчас попробовал и отлично сработало:
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()